# Replacing a tennis net

Tags: backyard

How do you replace a tennis net? Is it simple enough that it's worth doing myself, or should someone else be paid to do it?

Comment: What do you mean replace? Buy a new one and fit it to the existing tension system or make the net itself from string?

Comment: Existing tension system.

Comment: what is preventing you from determining how the existing net is attached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have only changed 1 net in the past and it was very simple. The cable tensioning system was a simple ratchet that was loosened and the old net removed from the side away from the tensioning crank and the new one installed. The one thing I did find is there are many different weight nets out there and some of the very cheap ones barely last a year.